# Accessing a parents variable from subclass php and parent keyword?

Tags: php, oop, class, object, parent-child

I have a parent class and a subclass, the parent class has a constructer that sets a `var` and I would like to use that `var` in the subclass, I have it working but am getting confused by the keyword `parent`?

Example

```
 class Sub extends Parent {
     public function foo() {
         echo $this -> myVar;
     }
 }

 class Parent {
     var $myVar;
     public function __construct() {
          $this -> myVar = 'a';
     }
 }
```

This worked and I get the value of `myVar`, but am I supposed to be using the keyword `parent` and when I do I get an error, example,

```
 class Sub extends Parent {
     public function foo() {
         echo parent -> myVar;
     }
 }

 class Parent {
     var $myVar;
     public function __construct() {
          $this -> myVar = 'a';
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, Parent is a reserved word. Second off, don't use `var` unless you're using an older version of PHP. You can use protected. You don't need to use the parent keyword to access the variable because the child class should inherit it. You can access it via `$this->myVar`

EDIT *to clarify*

You only need to use `parent::` when accessing methods of the base class or `static` variables of the base class. If you try to access a non static variable of the base class you will get an error `Access to undeclared static property" fatal error:`

Here's an example to get you started.

```
<?php
class Animal{
     protected $myVar;
     public function __construct() {
          $this->myVar = 'a';
     }
 }

class Cat extends Animal {
     public function foo() {
         echo $this->myVar;
     }
 }

$cat = new Cat(); 
$cat->foo(); 

?>
```

[Here's](http://codepad.org/OgdUkRpC) a working example of this code.

Comment: Why does it say in the manual to use the keyword `parent` when accesing the parent class? How come I don't have to use it here? Thanks again buddy

Comment: You only need to use `parent::` when accessing methods of the base class or static variables of the base class. If you try to access a non static variable of the base class you will get an error `Access to undeclared static property" fatal error:` Please mark this as answered if this answer helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keyword `parent` should be used to access methods or **static** variables of parent class only, so your first code is the proper one, since `$myVar` is not static.