# Name in the Properties class

Tags: php, class

Problem: get the name of a class property.

```
<?php 

class Vasya {
    public $name = __CLASS__;
}

$class = new Vasya();
echo $class->name; // result Vasya

class Petro extends Vasya { }

$class = new Petro();
echo $class->name; // result Vasya // Why???
```

How to get the name of a class inherited in property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get class name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103810/how-do-i-get-class-name-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a parents variable from subclass php and parent keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852028/accessing-a-parents-variable-from-subclass-php-and-parent-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

It is because, `$name` is declared only in the Parent Class; So it holds the class name of parent class. If you want your child class name, declare the variable in Child Class. In that case, it overrides the parent class's variable:

```
<?php

class Vasya {
    public $name = __CLASS__;
}

$class = new Vasya();
echo $class->name; // result Vasya

class Petro extends Vasya { 
    public $name = __CLASS__;
}

$class = new Petro();
echo $class->name; // result Petro
```